# How to get TransactionUnspentOutput as a hex encoded bytes string programmatically

Tags: node.js, cardano

So basically I want to convert a normal UTxO hash like:

```
550665309dee7e2f64d13f999297f001763f65fe50bb05524afc0990c7dce0c3
```

to a TransactionUnspentOutput as a hex encoded bytes string like:

```
828258205537396d59c1b0546bb9cec5cb6b930238af2d8998d24ca1d47e89a3dd400a8701825839016af9a0d2c9b5bce8999bc6430eb48f424399b73f0ecc143f40e8cac89b130cc3198a8594862fe25df331cb79447304dcd49712c86834fdf1821a00150bd0a1581cb0df0ee7dbb96b18b682a1091514f250eb0ec1122e6c4bf3b4d45123a14b436f6e766963743033363701
```

This is how it is done with a nami wallet implementation:

```
cardano.getUtxos(amount?: Value, paginate?: {page: number, limit: number}) : [TransactionUnspentOutput]
```

I tried to pass a UTxO into the lucid utxoToCore() function:

```
export const utxoToCore = (utxo: UTxO): Core.TransactionUnspentOutput => {
  const output = C.TransactionOutput.new(
    C.Address.from_bech32(utxo.address),
    assetsToValue(utxo.assets)
  );
  if (utxo.datumHash) {
    output.set_datum(
      C.Datum.new_data_hash(C.DataHash.from_bytes(fromHex(utxo.datumHash)))
    );
  }
  return C.TransactionUnspentOutput.new(
    C.TransactionInput.new(
      C.TransactionHash.from_bytes(fromHex(utxo.txHash)),
      C.BigNum.from_str(utxo.outputIndex.toString())
    ),
    output
  );
};
```

However the only output I get is:

```
TransactionUnspentOutput { ptr: 1247376 }
```

How to get the unpacked (?), or at least the right format I want, TransactionUnspentOutput?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to call an external library. Usually, in such cases, it will return you a memory address. Just like you have it in wasm calls through browser client. One way is to deserialize your object inside your node js code.

Maybe you can use some sorta utility function to get it as a string.

E.g. https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/blob/master/doc/getting-started/metadata.md#json-conversion

Hope this helps